# Why does Video JS HLS not work as expected only with 60 second segments?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, m3u8, http-live-streaming

To make a streaming service, I am serving m3u8 and ts files generated with AWS elastic transcoder.

The video player I am using is video js with videojs-contrib-hls.

I am providing the player with the master playlist 01.m3u8, which has the url to two different bitrate playlists 1M_.m3u8 amd 2M_.m3u8 (not important in my opinion)

Streaming works well when my segments are short. ex 10 seconds. However when I use 60 seconds the functionality does not work as expected. The buffer stops and seeking does not work. When I seek a new section of the movie, exception is caught.

```
Cannot read property 'pts' of undefined
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you post an example video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

It turns out that the problem was from the cloudfront. The files were cached and serving the undesired ts files.

It was solved by cache busting.

Comment: Hi can u tell me how to cache bust the worker files such as theoplayer.e.js in angular?